# Solution to render and visually sign PDF in Java Web Application

Tags: java, pdf, canvas, pdfbox

Wondering if anyone has any experience with displaying a PDF in a web application and allowing it to be editable. Specifically, I would like for users to be able to sign documents using their mouse, or finger on a tablet.

I have a solution that's functional, where I use PDF box to generate a pdf document, convert the pdf to an image and I overlay a canvas element over the image, which the user can then 'sign' (or technically, draw anything they want all over it).

I was hoping PDF could be used to display the pdf itself in JSF, but it doesn't seem so, right?
PDF.js is only a reader, so signing wouldn't be an option.

Do you think my hacked canvas approach is the best bet for a non-paid solution?

Thanks

Comment: "I was hoping PDF could be used to display the pdf itself in JSF" - what do you mean?!

Comment: I meant that I was hoping PDFBox could be used to display the pdf. You can create this PDocument, but I can't display the object without turning it into an image.

Comment: 1) You can edit your original text so that later readers understand it better. 2) No, PDFBox can't display without rendering it. The "PDFReader" command line application does just that. If you have already converted your PDF into images, I don't really see the problem. 3) Your solution sounds ok for me. (But thats just my opinion :-))

Comment: Do you know of any other solutions that don't require conversion to images? I'd just like something where I can render a pdf that a user can edit in a browser. Does that make sense? - I CAN do it, by converting the pdf to an image and overlaying a canvas, I just thought that there should be a better way of accomplish something that I'd imagine to be at least sort-of common...